# Can Java lambdas bind methods to their parameters?

Tags: java, lambda, function-pointers, function-binding

How to pass a method as a parameter using lambdas is discussed here:
[Java Pass Method as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter/25005082#25005082)

In other languages, namely C++, it is possible to bind a function to it's parameters using Lambdas - discussed here:
[Bind Vs Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930903/bind-vs-lambda)

Is it possible, in Java, to bind a method using lambdas?

If so, how would you accomplish this?

Edit >>>>

An example, by request, of what I am generally trying to do:

Be warned, there is pseudo code here.

```
public class DataView {

    private static ArrayList<Float> rectData = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private static ArrayList<Float> textData = new ArrayList<Float>();

    DataView(){

        //Pseudo Code:
        boundFunction mybind  = boundFunction(functionA, 5, 10);
        boundFunction mybind2 = boundFunction(functionB, 10, 12);

        iter(mybind);
        iter(mybind2);

    }

    //Method with pseudo parameter
    private void iter(functionSignature){
        for(Float i : textData){

            //Pseudo call to pseudo parameter
            functionSignature();

        }
    }

    private void functionA(int a, int b){
        //dostuff

    }

    private void functionB(int a, int b){
        //do other stuff

    }
```

}

Bare in mind, I'm not looking for 'another way to accomplish this functionality' - this example is to illustrate a general way in which I would like to use functions as parameters, and to bind parameters to those functions.

Edit>>>

Attempt using anonymous classes:

```
public class DataView {

    private class Bound{ 
        public void run(){}

    }

    private static ArrayList<Float> rectData = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private static ArrayList<Float> textData = new ArrayList<Float>();

    DataView(){

        Bound mybind = new Bound(){
            public void run(){
                functionA(5,10);
            }
        };

        Bound mybind2 = new Bound(){
            public void run(){
                functionB(5,10);
            }
        };

        iter(mybind);
        iter(mybind2);

    }

    private void iter(Bound function){
        for(Float i : textData){

            function.run();

        }
    }

    private void functionA(int a, int b){
        //dostuff

    }

    private void functionB(int a, int b){
        //do other stuff

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this? Did you run into any trouble?

Comment: I've done it in C++. I wouldn't know where to begin Java, and can't find any documentation, here or elsewhere.

Comment: Being able to pass actual functions in c++  is different than lambdas. In java there is no implementation to pass a function from a class. I hope that answers it i'm unsure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @Javant That's not entirely true, there is a thing called method references.

Comment: Could you post a short example of code doing what you want so Java experts can provide the Java analog (if any)? Because as it is, it's hard to say what *exactly* are you asking.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov Working on it....

Comment: edited.... added a code example

Comment: As a note, I would say that, to really understand lambdas in Java, you must first understand anonymous classes. Since lambdas are a shorthand for anonymous classes that implement an interface with only 1 method.

Comment: @JornVernee I gave that a shot in the edit. Does that look correct?

Comment: I'm trying to think of a way to wrap it, to make it prettier. But I think it's impossible. Hence, lambdas.

Comment: Not sure, but ... are you looking for the same thing that I asked for in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36336848/is-there-any-way-to-circumvent-the-typedness-of-lambda-expressions ?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said in other answers, Java requires an actual functional interface type to represent a function. This also applies to a bind operation which requires even two of such interfaces, one to represent the unbound function and one for the bound function:

```
public class DataView {
    interface NoArgFunction {
        void func();
    }
    interface TwoIntFunction {
        void func(int a, int b);
    }
    static NoArgFunction bind(TwoIntFunction f, int first, int second) {
        return () -> f.func(first, second);
    }

    private static ArrayList<Float> rectData = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private static ArrayList<Float> textData = new ArrayList<Float>();

    DataView(){
        NoArgFunction mybind  = bind(this::functionA, 5, 10);
        NoArgFunction mybind2 = bind(this::functionB, 10, 12);

        iter(mybind);
        iter(mybind2);
    }
    private void iter(NoArgFunction noArg){
        for(Float i : textData){
            noArg.func();
        }
    }
    private void functionA(int a, int b){
        //dostuff
    }
    private void functionB(int a, int b){
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

As a fun fact, on the bytecode level, there is a capability to combine a method with arguments without the intermediate step, which is exactly what is being used by the lambda expression `() -> f.func(first, second)`, which gets compiled into a synthetic method holding the lambda body and having two parameters for `first` and `second` which will be used at runtime to construct the `NoArgFunction` instance binding the current values of `first` and `second`.

But you can’t use this in Java source code. The only supported binding for existing methods is the one seen at the method references `this::functionA` and `this::functionB`, both binding the current `this` instance to the methods `functionA` and `functionB`. Well, using a lambda expression like
`NoArgFunction mybind = () -> functionA(5, 10);` in the first place without a `bind` method *does* short-cut the process…

So the bottom line is that there’s not much sense in trying to fight against the language trying to model a feature that isn’t intrinsically supported. Using a lambda expression instead of binding, together with a target type predefined for this purpose makes the code much simpler:

```
public class DataView {
    private static ArrayList<Float> rectData = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private static ArrayList<Float> textData = new ArrayList<Float>();

    DataView(){
        iter(x -> functionA(5, 10));
        iter(x -> functionB(10, 12));
    }
    private void iter(Consumer<Float> function){
        textData.forEach(function);
    }
    private void functionA(int a, int b){
        //dostuff
    }
    private void functionB(int a, int b){
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I got to say this is a pretty neat way to use lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code behind the second link:

```
auto dice = [&]() { return distribution(engine); };
```

The Java equivalent would be:

```
Supplier<...> dice = () -> distribution.apply(engine);
```

Where:

- `distribution` is a `java.util.function.Function`.
- `...` is the return type of the call.

For different combinations of in- and output types, there are different *functional interfaces* available in [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). You can also define you're own functional interface.

A lambda can be assigned to a variable with a functional interface type, as long as it matches the in- and output types defined by the interface's method.

---

Besides the lack of operator overloading and an `auto` equivalent, in Java. The types of the captured variables are all ways either reference types (all objects), or primitives.

You can *change* a captured reference type variable by calling (non-`const`, [there is no such thing in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)) methods on it. Like `apply` is called on `distribution` in the example.

All captured variables must be `final`, or effectively final. That means you can not assign new values to the captured variables. I.e. `distribution = someVal`, is not allowed, for both reference and primitive types.

Comment: Do you think the lambdas/interfaces can accomplish the type of pseudo code in the example?

Comment: @bigcodeszzer Yes you can, but Sergey already gave that answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you could do this:

```
public class DataView {

    private static ArrayList<Float> textData = new ArrayList<Float>();

    DataView(){
        Runnable mybind  = () -> functionA(5, 10);
        Runnable mybind2 = () -> functionB(10, 12);

        iter(mybind);
        iter(mybind2);

    }

    //Method with pseudo parameter
    private void iter(Runnable r){
        for(Float i : textData){
            r.run();
        }
    }

    private void functionA(int a, int b){
        //dostuff
    }

    private void functionB(int a, int b){
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

I've used `Runnable` because it's a ready out-of-the-box thing. But if you have some sort of complicated signature, you can easily declare a functional interface: that is, an interface with just one method (doesn't matter what the *method* is called if you're going to use lambdas). Then `iter` would accept a parameter of that interface type, and the lambdas will generally look like `(par1, par2) -> callYourFunction(par1, someValue, par2, someOtherValue)`. Those “values” are kind of “bound”, that is, copied much like you'd do with `[=]` in C++. But that's only as far as local variables are concerned (and they have to be effectively final anyway, as @Jorn mentions). But you can access *fields* of the enclosing class absolutely freely (meaning you can even change them). That's technically because `this` is captured by value, just like locals, and therefore you can modify the object `this` points to.

Comment: So you can use an interface to provide a type for a lambda? Could you use a class to do the same thing? I'm kind of confused as to how the runnable interface is calling the mybind through run()?

Comment: How does the runnable interface = the lambda? Does it invoke an implicit constructor, or store it somehow?