# Problems understanding the Stream.generate static method signature

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Why didn't Java choose this signature `<T> Stream<T> Stream.generate(Supplier<? extends T> supplier)` over this one `<T> Stream<T> Stream.generate(Supplier<T> supplier)` ?

I mean the below example (doesn't compile) is correct as a supplier of `String`s is also valid in a stream of `CharSequence`s, no ?

```
Supplier<String> constantHello = () -> "Hello";

long count = Stream.<CharSequence>generate(constantHello).count();
```

Comment: Make an example that compiles.

Comment: if i can make an example that compiles (and i can), there will be no problem lol.

Comment: This example doesn't really make sense. A `Supplier<String>` generates a `Stream<String>`. You can add a terminal operations that consumes `CharSequence` or even `Object`. PECS.

Comment: a `Supplier <String>` generates string objects which are valid in the context of a `Stream <CharSequence>` because we can reference a `String` through a `CharSequence` variable.

Comment: No. Generics are invariant. See, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18666878/2071828). You have a `Stream<String>`. That is what you have.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, i did understand the answer you pointed me at, but i still believe that a `Stream <CharSequence>` can be generated from a `Supplier <String>` because in the context of a `CharSequence`, a `String` is also valid. So why did java didn't reflected this on the signature of `Stream.generate` ?

Comment: As a motivation for why `Supplier<? extends T>` would be desirable here, suppose I have a `Supplier<PrivateFooImpl>` and want to return from my API a `Stream<Foo>`. I doubt we can easily answer why the method is declared the way it is, though, unless somebody such as @StuartMarks can explain it. Also note that you can get around this by saying `generate(constantHello::get)` or `.map(s -> (CharSequence) s)`.

Comment: @Radiodef can you explain to me why the tweak `constantHello::get` did the thing here ?

Comment: @BoristheSpider The example by Radiodef shows that this is in fact a reasonable use case, and I don't see a reason why they should not have supported `? extends T` (so +1 for the question). @marsouf : With the `::get` trick, you are basically creating a new supplier that has the type that is required there. (A very simplified explanation - there is some pretty hardcore type inference going on under the hood...)

Comment: It just lets type inference do its thing. `constantHello.get()` returns a `String` which is assignable to a `CharSequence`, so the method reference is valid. ([Simplified example](http://ideone.com/c1UN8G))

Comment: @marsouf The current form of the question might lead to answers focussing on irrelevant points (e.g. "It does not work because you wrote `<CharSequence>`", or workaround suggestions like the `::get`). If you  made clear that you cannot create a `Stream<CharSequence> st = Stream.generate(s);` from a `Supplier<String> s` (although there is no reason of why this should not be possible), then this could be avoided (But of course, that's up to you).

Comment: @Marco13 but it's not a `Stream<CharSequence>`, it's a `Stream<String>`. You can of course assign to `String<? extends CharSequence>`.

Comment: As i have heard before, the expression `constantHello::get` is  polymorphic, i mean it gets its type from the context, in this example the context was `Supplier <CharSequence>` so the type inference did the thing but for bare `constantHello`, this is not the case no ?

Comment: @BoristheSpider That's the point. If they had written `? extends T`, then it **could** be a (real) `Stream<CharSequence>`. The main point of generics being invariant is to keep type safety. But by streams being "read only", this is not applicable here.

Comment: @marsouf that's not what polymorphic means - your comment is rather ... confusing.

Comment: for example a bare `() -> "Hello"` has an unknown type unless we cast it or reference it from a variable with the appropriate type.

Comment: It doesn't have an unknown type; is has a very specific and defined type. It's a method that takes `void` and returns `String`. The type inference engine can deduce that it will work for an SMI rather takes `void` and returns anything `super String`. Do not confuse the two.

Comment: a lambda of the form `() -> String` can be a `Supplier <String>` or any other functional interface that takes `void` and returns a `String`, so it cannot have a specific predetermined type.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The type of a lambda and the type of the SMI it implements are not the same thing, that is what I am tying to tell you. Do not confuse 1) the type of the lambda 2) the type of the SMI and 3) the type inference system that matches them. Java is a very strongly typed language - everything always has a concrete type. What you are saying is equivalent to suggesting that `"Test"` does not have a type because it can be assigned to `String` or `Charsequence`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider While conceptually what you say is true and convincing, the type inference and mechanisms behind lambdas are quite bit more complicated than for "ordinary" objects. Particularly, a lambda expression "receives" a type that is deduced from the context where it is used. So the expression *itself* does not really "have" a type. Somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36336848/3182664

Comment: @marsouf This is an oversight and has been corrected in java 9.  See http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-

Comment: This is a very good observation. I remember that most Stream methods use generics like `? super T` or `? extends T` rather than just `T`. So I thought that this must be an oversight or something. And [yes, it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45776459/507738).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bug.  See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8132097

It has been corrected in java 9.  As you can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-), the method declaration is now

```
static <T> Stream<T> generate​(Supplier<? extends T> s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best perhaps to demonstrate with a different example.

Given a `Supplier` for, let's say, a double:

```
Supplier<Double> generator = Math::random;
```

We can, of course, create a `Stream` of doubles with this:

```
Stream<Double> ds = Stream.generate(generator);
```

But what if I wanted to have a `Stream` of numbers? After all, given that a double is a number, it only makes sense to be able to allow something like this:

```
Stream<Number> ns = Stream.generate(generator);
```

The latter of your two signatures would not allow the above statement to compile, as `generator` is not a `Supplier<Number>`. It is, though, a `Supplier<Double>`, and thus a `Supplier<? extends Number>`.