# Function which hold implementation of Runnable

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

I have this code:

```
new Thread(() -> {

    //do things

}).start();

new Thread(() -> {

    //do same things

}).start();
```

I know I can declare a function which hold lambda:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> add = x -> x + 1;
```

I want to make this function to hold implementation of `Runnable` from `new Thread`.

But I don't know what to put between `<>` of `Function`.

Comment: What is your requirement? This question is vague. What type of a function do you need?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I want to do this `Function<??, ??> runImpl = () -> { //runnable implementation }` and when I create a new Thread to do like this `new Thread(runImpl)`

Comment: You don't need a function. How about this: `Runnable task = () -> System.out.println("My task");`

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I didn't thinking at that, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, taking this idea one step further, as I asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36336848/3182664), is not possible. But fortunately, for your specific case, using `Runnable` will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.util.Function` can't represent a `Runnable` task because the Function takes in an argument and returns something, and conversely `Runnable.run` method does not take any argument and returns nothing. Even if you feel that `Runnable` is somewhat similar in nature to a `Function<Void, Void>`, even this assumption is wrong due to the same reason.

Given that `Runnable` is a single abstract method interface (It has only run method), you can merely implement it with a lambda expression.  Also notice that this lambda is just a more succinct syntactic sugar to orthodox anonymous inner classes. Here's how it looks.

```
Runnable task = () -> System.out.println("My task");
```

You can use this `Runnable` instance as an ordinary `Runnable` command in your program. Here's such an example usage.

```
Thread t = new Thread(task);
t.start();
```

Comment: …and the OP did already implement `Runnable` via lambda expression when using `new Thread(() -> {

    //do things

}).start();`…